flutter web how to make the web app window not resize when user resizes horizontally
I'm trying to achieve a result where when user increases or decreases horizontal size of the window the contents stays still and doesn't move so when window height decreases the contents are engulfed by bottom that is they remain the same place when user increases or decreases screen height

If you want to constrain the size of the UI, just use SizedBox with a fixed width or height or a ConstrainedBox with a minimum and maximum width or height.
If you want to know the available dimensions before building your widget (so that you could e.g. set the fixed or constrained sizes dynamically, based on window size), you can use LayoutBuilder.
